# Springs3 Hibernate3 annotation configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate-annotations

I am trying to configure springs3 for Hibernate3 annotations. I am getting following error.
I dubugged my application. its giving this exception while creating User object in getData().

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

    java.lang.NullPointerException
com.controller.userDAO.getdata(userDAO.java:32)
com.controller.MyController.userDetail(MyController.java:32)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Here is my application-context.xml

```
    <bean id="DataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
      <property name="username" value="root"/>
      <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>

   <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="DataSource" ref="DataSource"/>
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.hibernate.models" />
      <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
      </property>
   </bean>
```

DAO:

```
@Repository
 public class userDAO {

 @Autowired
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 public SessionFactory getSession() {
    return sessionFactory;
 }

 public void setSession(SessionFactory session) {
    this.sessionFactory = session;
 }

 @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
 public int getdata() {
    String hql = "select count(*) from User";
    User u = (User) getSession().openSession().createQuery(hql).uniqueResult();
    return 1;
 }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller 
public class MyController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/{x}/hi", params = {"a"})
public ModelAndView add(@RequestParam(value = "a") int na, @PathVariable int x) {
    System.out.println("print in console");
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("demo", "message", "Add method called for na and x :" + na + "+" + na + "=" + (na + na + x));
    System.out.println("obj created");
    return mv;
}

@RequestMapping("/user")
public ModelAndView userDetail() {
    userDAO u = new userDAO();
    int x;
    x = u.getdata();
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("demo", "message", "rows: "+x);
    return mv;
}
}
```

User bean for user table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user",catalog="test")
 public class User  implements java.io.Serializable {

 private Integer id;
 private String name;
 private int mobile;

public User() {
}

public User(String name, int mobile) {
   this.name = name;
   this.mobile = mobile;
}

 @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)

@Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name="name", nullable=false, length=20)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name="mobile", nullable=false)
public int getMobile() {
    return this.mobile;
}

public void setMobile(int mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}

}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
 <!-- Scan only for @Controllers -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" use-default-filters="false" >
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
<mvc:annotation-driven />


<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />
```

after annoting the user dao object in controller with Autowired annottation its giving following exception (UserDao and controller are in different packages) :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.dao.userDAO com.controller.MyController.u; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.dao.userDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)


org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.dao.userDAO com.controller.MyController.u; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.dao.userDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)



org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.dao.userDAO com.controller.MyController.u; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.dao.userDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)



org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.dao.userDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
```

Comment: Post the rest of the stack trace.

Comment: Now show us where you are using the `userDao`, your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring can only process an object it created. It can't inject other beans into instances it doesn't manage.

That's what you're doing here

```
userDAO u = new userDAO();
```

You're creating it yourself, so Spring know nothing about it and doesn't inject this field

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Instead, autowire the `userDao` bean into your `@Controller` class.

```
@Autowired
private userDao userDao;
```

and use that.

Comment: do in need to remove autowired annotation from SessionFactory?

Comment: @igniter If you do, Spring won't autowire anything and the field will remain `null`.

Comment: its not working.. i got other exception. i edited question for that. please check.

Comment: @igniter Your `userDAO` class is a `@Repository`. This is a specialization of `@Component`. It needs to be component scanned or a  `<bean>` element has to be declared for it explicitly.

Comment: @satirios i have userDAO and Controller class files in package package named as com.controller.dao and com.controller respectivly and i mentioned package name for auto scan in dispatcher-servlet.xml. So what is wrong there?

Comment: @igniter For one, get rid of the `use-default-filters`.

Answer (score 0):

check your application-context.xml, bean definition `sessionFactory`, property name `DataSource`. First letter should be simple `dataSource` .
try with `<property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource"/>`